FFmpeg mpeg2 issue
I'm trying to convert an mpeg2 video to h264, using the  command:
ffmpeg -i "C:\Video\HERCEGNO_CSODAORSZAGBAN\B1_t00.mkv" -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:04:18 -c:v libx264 -preset fast -crf 23 -c:a aac -b:a 192k -ac 2 "C:\Users\user\Videos\Princessa\PIDRKN01.mp4"
However, when I start converting it, ffmpeg start shows "invalid frame_pred_frame_dct" error messages:
[mpeg2video @ 0000017145339bc0] invalid frame_pred_frame_dctitrate=  27.0kbits/s speed=1.95x
Last message repeated 58 times
[mpeg2video @ 0000017145339bc0] invalid frame_pred_frame_dctbitrate=   0.2kbits/s speed=4.63x
Last message repeated 48 times
[mpeg2video @ 0000017145339bc0] invalid frame_pred_frame_dctbitrate=   0.1kbits/s speed= 4.2x
Last message repeated 40 times
[mpeg2video @ 0000017145339bc0] invalid frame_pred_frame_dctbitrate= 355.0kbits/s speed=3.87x
Last message repeated 38 times
[mpeg2video @ 0000017145339bc0] invalid frame_pred_frame_dctbitrate= 279.3kbits/s speed= 3.7x
Last message repeated 41 times
[mpeg2video @ 0000017145339bc0] invalid frame_pred_frame_dctbitrate= 455.2kbits/s speed=3.64x
Last message repeated 64 times
[mpeg2video @ 0000017145339bc0] invalid frame_pred_frame_dctbitrate= 356.2kbits/s speed=3.88x
Last message repeated 59 times
[mpeg2video @ 0000017145339bc0] invalid frame_pred_frame_dctbitrate= 444.2kbits/s speed=4.01x
Last message repeated 37 times
[mpeg2video @ 0000017145339bc0] invalid frame_pred_frame_dctbitrate= 399.1kbits/s speed= 3.9x
Last message repeated 33 times
[mpeg2video @ 0000017145339bc0] invalid frame_pred_frame_dctbitrate= 369.1kbits/s speed=3.74x
Last message repeated 31 times
[mpeg2video @ 0000017145339bc0] invalid frame_pred_frame_dctbitrate= 457.8kbits/s speed=3.61x
Last message repeated 31 times
[mpeg2video @ 0000017145339bc0] invalid frame_pred_frame_dctbitrate= 427.0kbits/s speed=3.52x
Last message repeated 40 times
[mpeg2video @ 0000017145339bc0] invalid frame_pred_frame_dctbitrate= 490.6kbits/s speed=3.52x
Last message repeated 43 times
[mpeg2video @ 0000017145339bc0] invalid frame_pred_frame_dctbitrate= 454.7kbits/s speed= 3.5x
Last message repeated 37 times
How can I solve this issue?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

What does ffprobe -i "C:\Video\HERCEGNO_CSODAORSZAGBAN\B1_t00.mkv" output look like?
